# Should I say "context" or "contexts"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I just asked about the phrase "Eastern Seaboard" in another question. I used the sentence:

> Is "seaboard" used in other contexts?

I thought this didn't sound very good, so I changed it to:

> Is "seaboard" used in other context?

Should *context* ever be pluralized? Or is it a mass noun?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[*Context* is not a mass noun, and takes the plural *-s*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/context#Noun).

Answer (score 4):

"Another context" not "other context"

Comment: yeah maybe that's what I meant to say :) must have been too early in the morning.

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted the top two answers, because they are both correct.

To clarify, it should be either

> ... in another context?"

or

> ... in other contexts?

Both are correct and acceptable, but never "in other context?"

Answer (score 1):

Example: 'The word "seaboard" can be used in the context of a coastline; it may also be used in (many) other contexts.'

When there's one, it's context, when more than one (or possibly so) it's plural - contexts.

Using "any other context" or "another context" sounds to me like you are pre-suposing there is only one other, although it would not be very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two options you supplied,

> ... in other contexts?

is correct.

Another option,

> ... in another context?

is also correct, but whether you use it will depend on whether there are multiple "contexts" or just one, to consider.  Of course, "context" is singular, indicating only one; while "contexts" is plural, indicating many. Thus, to say

> ... in other context?

would be incorrect, as "other" implies multiple, while "another" implies one.